# Cross references with Django

Tags: python, django

I want to use a model in a validation function (validators.py), therefore I import the model at the beginning of the file

```
from models import ModelIWantToUse
```

but models.py includes an import to validator functions in validators.py

```
from validators import some_validations
```

This causes a cross imports, raising:

```
ImportError: cannot import name
```

Which is the best way to make imports, location of functions and classes to not end up in cross imports problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just import the necessary functions right after the definition of your function or method where you wish to use it.

```
def foo():
    from validators import some_validations
```

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure about that. It feels weird to me... not being able to group all the imports